# How do you get an NSImageView to refresh when its image changes on disk?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsimage

I've got an `NSImageView` bound to a file on disk through its `valuePath` binding. When I write out a new image to that location, I want the `NSImageView` to show the new image. How can I accomplish this?

I've tried calling `-didChangeValueForKey:` and `-willChangeValueForKey:` on the object to which the view is bound, and declaring a `+keyPathsForValuesAffecting___` method on the object, but I have a feeling these KVO-based methods don't have an impact because the image's path isn't changing, just its contents.

I also tried calling `-setNeedsDisplay` and `-updateCell:` on the image view after the change took place, but that doesn't work, either.

**Update**

I changed the `-imagePath` property (a calculated property) on my bound object to `@""` immediately before writing the new image, and then back to the correct path immediately after. This does achieve the desired effect, but I was hoping for a more correct method present in the API. It feels like a hack.

Comment: NSImages do some caching. If you have access to the image view at the time the file is being updated, is there any reason you can't just call setImage: on the view again?

Comment: As mentioned, I don't call `-setImage:`, I'm using bindings on the `valuePath` property

Comment: Have you tried writing a different value entirely (like an empty string or a bogus path) and then immediately restoring the original value for the property?

Comment: @KevinGrant I was going to, but the property is calculated, so that wouldn't be as easy as if it was a normal ivar-backed property. And that also seems like it would be a hack. I'd like to know if there's a "right" way to do it.

Comment: @KevinGrant I confirmed that does work (and updated the question), but I'd still like to know if there's a more proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Set a different value (empty string `@""`) and then restore the original value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, as mentioned above, I consider this more of a workaround than a solution.

Comment: Also, while this works for an `NSTableView`, it doesn't do the trick for `NSCollectionView`. Any progress in the last couple years?

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure that `needsDisplay = true` is the right way to do this, but you also have to be running on the main thread or changes won't happen.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the File inspector in interface builder, and untick "Use Auto Layout".

Comment: the question is about how to detect the change of the image source, not about how to draw/layout it